# How can I permanently instruct windows7 to default my user data like libraries to other than boot disk?

Tags: windows-7, user-folders

I like to use my SSD bootdisk for programs only and have all data on another drive. That's easier for backup too.

Comment: This question has been answered in many forms already.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this would be to make an unattended Windows Setup answer file using [System Image Manager](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc722301%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) from the [Microsoft Deployment Toolkit](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=3bd8561f-77ac-4400-a0c1-fe871c461a89&displaylang=en&tm), where you can specify many different things for a customised Windows installation.

However, the whole process is quite involved for people unfamiliar with it, and there are a lot of options to wade through.

[image: System Image Manager]

---

Of course, you can always remove the default Library locations instead, and make the default save locations on your secondary hard drive, which would be a lot easier.

Just right-click the Library in the left-hand panel and select Properties.  Select the default locations and press Remove, and then add your location(s) from your secondary drive, using the 'Include a folder' button.  If you add more than one location, you need to select one of them as the default save location.

Comment: "Of course, you can ......." I thought I noticed that the libraries kept initiating the old locations. Can you give some more specific steps for your recommended move to another drive? Thanks

Comment: @UniqueHorn: I added some instructions on doing that.

Answer (score 1):

If by data you mean you "Users" profile, then there is this

http://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/change-windows-default-user-profile-directory/

Usual caveats apply:

Create backup of the data !

Restore Point(s)

And Preferably image the Drive prior to relocating the data