# How to change windows hard drive

Tags: windows, windows-10, hard-drive

I have a lot of stuff in my Local disk C which as you might know is the default drive in windows what I want to do is that I want to switch from C drive to F drive to be my default drive so all the new programs getting installed would be in my F drive.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Moving program files or user to E:/](https://superuser.com/questions/882180/moving-program-files-or-user-to-e)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When installing a program you are asked where you want to install it, and you can just choose a different drive.

Simply moving installed programs with copy-paste or various tools is not recommended and will cause them to malfunction or stop working.

Possible working solutions if you want to keep using C drive would be:

- uninstall programs and games and then reinstall them to F drive
- move folder contents (not the folder themselves) for Downloads and Documents
- delete unnecessary files using Disk Cleanup tool and also option "Clean up system files"
- reduce the size of your system restore allocated space and delete some older restore points

Alternative working solution (better) is:

- use a partition manager tool to clone C to F (which should be empty before), then go to BIOS and make F drive your primary boot drive. Then the bigger F drive becomes the new C and you can format the older drive to gain some space.

Comment: thnx, but not every program asks the location ya know but your solutions were so far the best the answer is accepted from me.